# MYSQL Update statement not working, no associated error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I've seen a few posts dealing with UPDATE statements in MySQL, but none of them seem to apply to my specific situation.

I have the following code:

```
$result = "SELECT iso_date FROM open_lab_report WHERE iso_date = current_timestamp";

if(!mysqli_query($link, $result)) {

  $sql = "INSERT INTO open_lab_report (iso_date, lab_monitor, incidentReport) VALUES (current_timestamp, '$lab_monitor', 1)";

}else{

  $sql = "UPDATE open_lab_report SET incidentReport = 1 WHERE iso_date = current_timestamp";

} 

if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
  echo "Query failed, code: " . mysqli_errno($link);
}
```

Essentially, I'm trying to check to see if an entry exists. If it exists, then update it. If the entry doesn't exist, then make it.

The INSERT statement executes perfectly. However, the UPDATE statement does nothing. There is no error message, and no changes made in my table.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there's no error. Just your sql-query returns nothing. It doesn't mean that result of `mysqli_query` is falsy.

Comment: You can't use current_timestamp in that way.  Current_timestamp is NOW. 
 Think of it like from the movie Spaceballs.  When do this happen?  Now, but when did now happen?  You just missed it.  Use something else that specifys a non dynamic point in time.

Comment: the else will never get executed as that query in if statement will always be executed with or without any result sot this if statement will be always be true

Comment: *"I'm trying to check to see if an entry exists."* - you need to either `COUNT()` or `num_rows()` it and check if it's `>0` while checking for a specific record. Least, that's what I take from this.

Comment: Search the web for *IODKU*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Forbs stated, your UPDATE statement will not result in any changes since you are filtering based on "current_timestamp", which will be whatever time the query executes. What you need to do instead is pass an existing timestamp into your code so that it updates whatever existing record already has that as its iso_date.

See the example below for how you can change your code.

```
//this is whatever your time is that you are looking for a record for
$isoDateDT = '2018-08-01 08:15:00';//human readable datetime
$isoDateTS = strtotime($isoDateDT);//unix timestamp
$result = "SELECT * FROM open_lab_report WHERE iso_date = $isoDateTS";
if(!mysqli_query($link, $result)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO open_lab_report (iso_date, lab_monitor, incidentReport) VALUES ($isoDateTS, '$lab_monitor', 1)";
} else {
    $sql = "UPDATE open_lab_report SET incidentReport = 1 WHERE iso_date = $isoDateTS";
}

if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "Query failed, code: " . mysqli_errno($link);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you and @Forbs. That was it. I ended up just using $isoDateDT = date('Y-m-d');. I didn't need to pass it through strtotime().

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct your if statement checking.
In your Case you can count number of entries with same timestamp as current timestamp.
and then

if count<1 then you can UPDATE ,otherwise INSERT.

EXAMPLE:

```
$result = "SELECT iso_date FROM open_lab_report WHERE iso_date = current_timestamp";
$row=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($link, $result))
if($row<1){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO open_lab_report (iso_date, lab_monitor, incidentReport) VALUES (current_timestamp, '$lab_monitor', 1)";

}else{

  $sql = "UPDATE open_lab_report SET incidentReport = 1 WHERE iso_date = current_timestamp";

} 

if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
  echo "Query failed, code: " . mysqli_errno($link);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that as well. It wasn't why my UPDATE statement wasn't working, but it also needed to be fixed.